# PHP and Cron jobs

Tags: php, cron

I have some scripts which need to be run only through the CLI interface. So, when I execute them through Cron jobs, will they run through the CLI interface or some other daemon(if thats the right word to use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cron job (and/or [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)) will allow you to specify which program to use.  Typically, it will use the same program you use as a CLI.  PHP does not have a service (though it can use other services, like Apache).

Comment: i checked, it does use CLI. Thanks!